# setInterval обновление значений

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var sel = document.querySelector("select");
sel.addEventListener("change", function() {
var val = sel.selectedOptions[0].id.split('-')
sel.selectedOptions[0].value = getRandomInt(+val[0], +val[1])

setInterval(function() {
        sel.selectedOptions[0].value = getRandomInt(+val[0], +val[1])
      }, 5000);

console.log(sel.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="periodicity">
  <option id="1-60" value="">Одуванчик
  </option>
  <option id="25-70" value="">Чабрец
  </option>
  <option id="1-100" value="">Полынь
  </option>
</select>
```

Помогите с setInterval нужно чтобы каждые 5 секунд обновляло значение

Comment: что не работает?

Comment: А если `console.log()` засунуть внутрь `setInterval()`?))

Comment: Приведенный код работает.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что на каждое событие `change` будет запускаться дополнительный таймер.

Comment: Коммент не относящийся к вопросу: Ваша функция `getRandomInt` никогда не сможет вернуть значение `max`.

Comment: а как это реализовать?

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


var sel = document.querySelector("select");
//----------------------------------------------------------------
var options = sel.options; // 
//----------------------------------------------------------------
setInterval(function() {
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Каждые 5 сек меняет value ...
  Object.values(options).forEach(function(el) {
    var val = el.id.split('-');
    el.value = getRandomInt(+val[0], +val[1])
    console.log(el.value);
  })

}, 5000);
//----------------------------------------------------------------

sel.addEventListener("change", function() {
  /// Возможно эта часть вам уже не нужна...
  var val = sel.selectedOptions[0].id.split('-')
  sel.selectedOptions[0].value = getRandomInt(+val[0], +val[1])
  console.log(sel.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="periodicity">
  <option id="1-60" value="">Одуванчик
  </option>
  <option id="25-70" value="">Чабрец
  </option>
  <option id="1-100" value="">Полынь
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать чтобы менялось только 1 значение выбранного поля?

Comment: @Николай У вас и "менялось" одно, выбранное поле.