# Функция возвращающая число в определенном промежутке, не возвращает максимально возможное значение

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Функция getRandomInt не возвращает значение max, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: `(max - min)` заменить на `(max - min + 1)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840796/setinterval-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#comment1348273_840796

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) возвращает значение в интервале `[0; 1)`, то есть не включая верхнюю границу.

При умножении на `(max - min)` интервал меняется на следующий `[0; max-min)`, опять не включая верхнюю границу.

При дальнейшем сдвиге на `min` получим интервал `[min, max)`

Следовательно чтобы `max` входил в интервал после сдвига интервал должен оканчиваться `max+1`

Значит до сдвига: `max+1 - min`

Отсюда получаем множитель `max+1 - min` вместо `max - min`

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1 - min)) + min;
}
```